# Clean undefined items in Numeric Array and sort it by javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

i have an array created inside `for loops`

below is an array of numbers contains undefined items & i dont know the right way to remove undefined items and sort it finely , see:

```
2426,3045,,1680,,,1323,,,,1311
```

after sorting , here is first two items merged :

```
24263045,1680,,1323,,,1311,,,,
```

Here is my code:

```
var textcontent = 'larg text content larg text content larg text content larg text content larg text content larg text content';
var words = 'content larg text';
var word = words.split(' ');

for(var i=0;i<word.length;i++){
var kx=[];
kx[i] = textcontent.indexOf(word[i]);

function sortNumber(a,b) {
return a - b;
}
//trying to sort that
var vk = kx.sort(sortNumber);
document.write(vk);
// it returns something like this
// 24263045,1680,,1323,,,1311,,,, 
}
```

How to remove undefined items and sort it to be

```
1311,1323,1680,2426,3045
```

Comment: Why are you sorting inside the loop?

Comment: i'm trying alot to be out of loop but i have big code inside for loop , cant find workarounds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of *filter()* .

```
var arr = [2426,3045,,1680,,,1323,,,,1311];
function test(array){
    var arr = array.filter(function(item){
      return item && item!='';//Check if string item is empty.
    })
    console.log(arr);
    return arr;
}
//Call
var arr = test(arr).sort();//To sort
```

Comment: it returns `undefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefined` with me !

Comment: yes big thanks its right & working but not with my ex .. is that because loops ?

Comment: @EgySuccess. I am not sure what are you trying to do inside for loop but try to declare `var kx=[];` outside for loop and c.

Comment: Egy said some of his array values were undefined, not blank strings. I think you'd cover the most bases by checking `item !== 0 && item` (so, the second condition is just Boolean-evaluating it)